# Unity2D destroy collider gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I create clone the gameobject . I want to destroy. if I want to gameobject is destroy  collider on the "plane" . but not working.and  I want to  touch the gameobject destroy.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D  ot )  
{
    if (ot.gameObject.tag == "plane") {
        Destroy(ot.gameObject);
    }
}
```

//Create clone this code

```
IEnumerator spawn()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2 (((i+5)%15) , Random.Range(5,20) ) , Quaternion.identity); 

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.30f); 
    }
}
```

Comment: OnTriggerEnter2D gets called ?

Answer (score 2):

These are my guesses:
1. Your gameobject does not have Rigidbody2D component. You might be using Rigidbody (not Rigidbody2D).
2. The collider of "plane" is not set as Trigger.

Please make sure all physics components are 2D: Colliders are 2D, Rigidbodies are 2D.

Comment: In your OnTriggerEnter2D, the logic is: "If a plane hits your game object, destroy that plane". Is that what you want? From your question, the logic should be: "If a plane hit your game object, destroy the game object". You should change: "Destroy(ot.gameObject);" to "Destroy(this.gameObject);"  

Note that: you are destroying the "plane", so there will be no "plane" left to collide.